# JQuery animate not running for element dynamically changed

Tags: javascript, events, jquery-animate, jquery

Okay, I am at my wits end.  Here is my code, or at least, the section of it that I think is causing the problem/relevant to my question.

```
//clicking back contacts scenario
$("#feat-back-arrow").live("click", function () {
    contractFeature();
});

//undo expand function for feature
//
//
function contractFeature() {
    $(feat_expanded_div).removeClass("expanded-feat");
    //actual slow animation
    var d = {};
    var speed = 400;
    d.width = feat_orig_width;
    d.height = feat_orig_height;
    d.left = feat_offset_left;
    d.top = feat_offset_top;
    d.marginRight = "0px"
    $(feat_expanded_div).animate(d, speed);
    showFeatures();
    returnFeatureHeader(feat_expanded_div);
    ExpandFeature = false;
}
```

I dynamically generate a button called `#feat-back-arrow` that when clicked, calls `contractFeature()`, and in specific, runs an animation event.  This event is not working with `feat_expanded_div` (which I define above as a global variable and such, and use it in other functions in `contractFeature()`).  Nothing happens at all.

Now, if I change a section of my code to this:

```
var d = {};
        var speed = 400;
        d.width = feat_orig_width;
        d.height = feat_orig_height;
        d.left = feat_offset_left;
        d.top = feat_offset_top;
        d.marginRight = "0px"
        $("div").animate(d, speed);
```

Changing it so it just runs on all divs, it works fine.  I know the problem isn't with defining `feat_expanded_div`, because as I said, the function `returnFeatureHeader()` carries it as a parameter just fine.

I think it has something to do with a `.live` event with an animate event, but literally, any insight right now would be very helpful.  =)

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried wrapping `feat_expanded_div` in quotes just to see what would happen?

Comment: feat_expanded_div is a variable, but i can try it, it is defined as
var feat_expanded_div = $("blahblah element");

Comment: placing it in "" yields the same nonexistent effect =(

Comment: Hmm... This is puzzling... What happens if you pass it as a parameter into `contractFeature()`?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's tough to say without seeing code, but I created this simple fiddle that (I think) does what you're saying: http://jsfiddle.net/LBDqR/ (dynamically creates a button and then animates a div) - I was wondering if your code does something similar?

Answer (score -1):

If feat_expanded_div is a jquery object

( being declared like so.. var feat_expanded_div = $("blahblah element"); )

Then you shouldn't wrap it in another $(), in otherwords just do this

feat_expanded_div.animate(d, speed);

Comment: It seems to be perfectly fine to wrap a jQuery object in $() - http://jsfiddle.net/n9Hp3/